# Normalize type family instance within Template Haskell splice

Tags: haskell, ghc, template-haskell, type-families, data-kinds

I'm using the `genifunctors` package to generate a functor instance for a type whose definition involves type families.

The first module defines the data type itself:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
module Temp where

data Record (p :: (*,*))

type family Fst p where Fst (Record '(a,b)) = a
type family Snd p where Snd (Record '(a,b)) = b

data Bar s = Bar {
  field_a :: Fst s,
  field_b :: Snd s
}

newtype Baz a = Baz { getBaz :: Bar (Record '(Maybe a, [a])) }
```

This works just as expected:

```
λ> import Temp 
λ> :t Baz $ Bar (Just "a") ["b"] 
Baz $ Bar (Just "a") ["b"] :: Baz [Char]
```

The `Functor` instance is defined in a separate module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Temp2 where

import Temp

import Data.Generics.Genifunctors

instance Functor (Baz a) where
  fmap = $(genFmap ''Baz)
```

And gives this error:

```
λ> import Temp1
src/Temp2.hs:9:12-24: Exception when trying to run compile-time code: …
  unexpected TyCon: FamilyI (ClosedTypeFamilyD Temp.Fst [PlainTV p_1627394000] (Just StarT) [TySynEqn [AppT (ConT Temp.Record) (AppT (AppT (ConT GHC.Tuple.(,)) (VarT a_1627394001)) (VarT b_1627394002))] (VarT a_1627394001)]) []
Code: genFmap ''Baz
In the splice: $(genFmap ''Baz)
```

This happens because `genifunctors`, just like `geniplate`, can only handle
type constructors from `newtype` or `data` declarations.

This could be fixed by normalizing the type before recursively inspecting it.

So, is there a way to do so within a Template Haskell splice? (i.e. 
within the `Q` monad?)

Comment: The function `genFmap` is using `reify` in order to get information about `Baz`. You are not passing it a representation of the type, so you can't "normalize the type" before passing it to `genFmap`. So you would have to modify the source of the package. You can write your own program which will manipulate the `Type` AST in order to remove trivial applications of type families ("normalize"), but TH will not do it automatically (of course this is non-trivial problem in general).

Comment: @user2407038 can you turn your comment into an answer, since it seems to answer the question?